# Swift: How to invalidate a timer if the timer starts from a function?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a `timer` variable in a function like this:

```
timer = NSTimer()

func whatever() {
   timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerbuiltingo", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

when I try to stop the timer in the resulting `timerbuiltingo` function like this:

```
func timerbuiltingo() {
   timer.invalidate()
   self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

It doesn't stop it. How should I be doing this?

Comment: Where does the `timerbuiltin` variable come from?

Comment: sorry, timerbuiltin should just be timer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to be able to stop the timer at *any* point in time, make it an instance variable.

If you will only ever need to stop it in the method it is called, you can have that method accept an `NSTimer` argument.  The timer calling the method will pass itself in.

```
class ClassWithTimer {
    var timer = NSTimer()

    func startTimer() {
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerTick:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func timerTick(timer: NSTimer) {
        println("timer has ticked")
    }
}
```

With this set up, we can now either call `self.timer.invalidate()` or, within `timerTick`, we can call `timer.invalidate()` (which refers to the timer which called the method).