# How do I reset & Pause a timer without using timer.invalidate()

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm looking to reset and Pause a timer with the click of a UI Button, but am having some trouble "resetting" the timer. Can anyone help? When starting the time , resetting, and starting again, the update func is called multiple times, messing up the countdown.

```
@IBAction func startTimer (_ sender: AnyObject) {
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    Reset.isHidden = false
    StartButton.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func resetButton (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Reset.isHidden = true
    StartButton.isHidden = false
    count = 200
    invalidate.t
}



func update()  {
    if (count > 0) {
        let minutes = String(count / 60)
        let seconds = String(count % 60)
        if (seconds == "0") {
        CountDown.text = minutes + ":" + seconds + "0"
        } else {
        CountDown.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }
        count -= 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `timer.invalidate()` inside your `resetButton` method?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have!.."Use of unresolved indentifier 'timer'"

Comment: You would need to make the timer an instance variable inside of your class so that it's accessible elsewhere.

Comment: This is swift, I thought variable were accessible anywhere as long as they were not marked private?

Comment: See the selected answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579237/swift-how-to-invalidate-a-timer-if-the-timer-starts-from-a-function

Comment: Didn't to see to help, timer.invalidate() simply does not work

Comment: In swift, all variables called inside a function remain local to that function. To make a variable accessible from anywhere it needs to be declared outside of a function.